# How do I efficiently remove the text in one column from another column in an R data frame?

Tags: r, apply

I've tried both apply (apply & lapply) and foreach + doParallel, but I think I'm lacking complete understanding of these two concepts to be able to make them work.

Ultimately, I want to look at at list of Sub_IDs (as well as Sub_Sub_IDs) and remove them from the Text column.  The Text column comes as-is and is manually entered by someone (it's text notes), so the Sub_IDs and Sub_Sub_IDs will be in will-nilly order and may not all be in the Text column; so, I can't depend on an exact match for the entire list.  The Sub_ID and Sub_Sub_ID columns can be pivoted to 1 per row instead of combined and separated by commas, but I found that pulling them all into one row made more sense.

Below is what I've been able to come up with which works as expected, but it's SLOWWWWW (actual data has 220K+ rows).

**Sample data:**

| ID | Text | Sub_ID | Sub_Sub_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some text sub_id 1,2,3 and sub_sub_id 1,2,3 | 3,2,1 | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | some text sub_id 1,2,3 and sub_sub_id 1,2,3 | 1,2,3 | 2,3,1 |
| 3 | some text sub_id 4,5 and sub_sub_id 1,2,3 | 4,5 | 1,2,3 |
| 4 | some text sub_id 4 and sub_sub_id 1,2 | 4 | 2,1 |
| 5 | some text sub_id 5 and sub_sub_id 3 | 5 | 3 |

**Current for loop:**

```
library(stringr)

for (r in 1:nrow(sample_data)) {
  for (Sub_ID in unlist(str_split(sample_data[r]$Sub_ID,','))) {
    sample_data[r]$Text <- str_replace_all(sample_data[r]$Text,Sub_ID,'')
  }
  for (Sub_Sub_ID in unlist(str_split(temp[r]$Sub_Sub_ID,','))) {
    sample_data[r]$Text <- str_replace_all(sample_data[r]$Text,Sub_Sub_ID,'')
  }
}
```

**Desired output for row 1 in above table:**
Text = `some text sub_id and sub_sub_id`

**Is there a way to make this faster?**  I've tried apply and foreach as previously stated, but I couldn't get either to work.

With apply, I really struggled with the interdependent columns (since I'm looking at one column for the values to delete from another column).  I received a couple different error messages and it seemed like I wasn't going to be able to make it work/was going to be too complicated for an apply.

And foreach gave me the below, super helpful error message:

> Error in { : task 8 failed - "replacement has 0 rows, data has 213474"

My ultimate goal with this is to create a data source for a word cloud in Tableau and I'm trying to remove the Sub_IDs and Sub_Sub_IDs since they'd be the biggest words in the word cloud simply because they're used in every comment they're in; however, they don't really guide any decisions/help folks.

Comment: I don't understand yet what the desired output is. I also suspect that there is faster vectorized approach. I'm not sure parallelization is a good fit for the problem since each step is (potentially) quite fast.

Comment: Added an example of the desired output for clarity

Answer (score 1):

From those loops it seems that whitespace and punctuation does not play a role here, so here's a kind of dirty regex approach where we just paste `Sub_ID*` columns to form a regular expression and test `str_remove_all()` with 220k rows:

```r
library(stringr)
sample_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,                                         ~Text, ~Sub_ID, ~Sub_Sub_ID,
   1L, "some text sub_id 1,2,3 and sub_sub_id 1,2,3", "3,2,1",     "1,2,3",
   2L, "some text sub_id 1,2,3 and sub_sub_id 1,2,3", "1,2,3",     "2,3,1",
   3L,   "some text sub_id 4,5 and sub_sub_id 1,2,3",   "4,5",     "1,2,3",
   4L,       "some text sub_id 4 and sub_sub_id 1,2",     "4",       "2,1",
   5L,         "some text sub_id 5 and sub_sub_id 3",     "5",         "3"
  )

# generate 220k rows 
sample_220k <- rep(list(sample_data), 220000/nrow(sample_data)) |> do.call(rbind, args = _)
str(sample_220k)
#> tibble [220,000 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ ID        : int [1:220000] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
#>  $ Text      : chr [1:220000] "some text sub_id 1,2,3 and sub_sub_id 1,2,3" "some text sub_id 1,2,3 and sub_sub_id 1,2,3" "some text sub_id 4,5 and sub_sub_id 1,2,3" "some text sub_id 4 and sub_sub_id 1,2" ...
#>  $ Sub_ID    : chr [1:220000] "3,2,1" "1,2,3" "4,5" "4" ...
#>  $ Sub_Sub_ID: chr [1:220000] "1,2,3" "2,3,1" "1,2,3" "2,1" ...

tictoc::tic()
sample_220k$Text <- str_remove_all(sample_220k$Text, str_glue("[{sample_220k$Sub_ID},{sample_220k$Sub_Sub_ID}]"))
tictoc::toc()
#> 1.44 sec elapsed

head(sample_220k)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>      ID Text                                Sub_ID Sub_Sub_ID
#>   <int> <chr>                               <chr>  <chr>     
#> 1     1 "some text sub_id  and sub_sub_id " 3,2,1  1,2,3     
#> 2     2 "some text sub_id  and sub_sub_id " 1,2,3  2,3,1     
#> 3     3 "some text sub_id  and sub_sub_id " 4,5    1,2,3     
#> 4     4 "some text sub_id  and sub_sub_id " 4      2,1       
#> 5     5 "some text sub_id  and sub_sub_id " 5      3         
#> 6     1 "some text sub_id  and sub_sub_id " 3,2,1  1,2,3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I tried this and got an error message: `Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : In a character range [x-y], x is greater than y.`  The Sub_ID and Sub_Sub_ID columns sometimes have dashes and such in them - is that what you were referring to with the "whitespace and punctuation does not play a role here" comment? .... :(

Comment: For clarity - I mean the actual IDs themselves may have dashes/colons/etc. in them - the separator of the IDs **in the ID columns** will always be a comma because that's in my SQL script with STRING_AGG

Comment: I'm afraid it makes it a different task as in the data sample all values are strictly single-digit numericals. I will probably not update it, at least not in a day or two, but for others please consider adding examples that would cover those cases  -- answers you get are mostly as good as the test data you provide. And in this case it might provide some valuable context on what drove you towards those loops in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

attempting to expand on margusl's approach, theres lot thats not understood about your setup and goals, but you mention wordcloud and wanting to preprocess your data to make the wordcloud result more meaningful; to me theres an implication that no sub_id or sub_sub_id is ever meaningful. in that case, theres a possibility that it may be 'cheaper' to make a remove list up front of all sub ids and sub subids and resolve to remove them all from the text, regardless of the rowwise associations.

Heres an example of doing that.
For me it goes about 3x faster than margusl's first prototype; given the same conditions/assumptions

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tictoc)

sample_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,                                         ~Text, ~Sub_ID, ~Sub_Sub_ID,
  1L, "some text sub_id 1,2,3 and sub_sub_id 1,2,3", "3,2,1",     "1,2,3",
  2L, "some text sub_id 1,2,3 and sub_sub_id 1,2,3", "1,2,3",     "2,3,1",
  3L,   "some text sub_id 4,5 and sub_sub_id 1,2,3",   "4,5",     "1,2,3",
  4L,       "some text sub_id 4 and sub_sub_id 1,2",     "4",       "2,1",
  5L,         "some text sub_id 5 and sub_sub_id 3",     "5",         "3"
)

# generate 220k rows 
sample_220k_start <- rep(list(sample_data), 220000/nrow(sample_data)) |> do.call(rbind, args = _)
str(sample_220k)

sample_220k <- sample_220k_start
tictoc::tic()
remove_list <- c(str_split(unique(sample_220k$Sub_ID),pattern = ",") |> unlist() |> unique(),
str_split(unique(sample_220k$Sub_Sub_ID),pattern = ",") |> unlist() |> unique()) |> unique()
remove_list_regex <- paste0(c(',',remove_list),collapse = "|") # remove from all rows any id regardless of which original row it was associated with, also remove commas
sample_220k$Text <- str_remove_all(sample_220k_start$Text, remove_list_regex)
tictoc::toc()
```